# How to Uninstall A Plugin (Seed Fu) From Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins

We installed Seed Fu to add in seed data in rails, then noticed that it isn't working right - doing some digging, we realized that Rails 2.3.8 comes with seeding built in, and seed fu might be deprecated.

Now we're trying to uninstall seed fu, but are not sure of the right way to do it.

We installed seed fu using

```
script/plugin install git://github.com/mbleigh/seed-fu.git
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Plugins installed via `script/plugin install` are installed in the **vendor/plugins/** directory.

It's safe to just `rm -rf vendor/plugins/seed-fu`. Don't forget to remove it from source control as well.

Comment: This seemed to break things for us - but I'll look into it more and get back to you.

Comment: If it is breaking things for you then that means you (or another plugin/gem) are calling methods somewhere that depend on it. You'll need to take good looks at your error messages and deal with them one by one.